# In how many different ways can tests A, B, C be performed based on the following conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations, puzzle

> Suppose a patient has to undergo, on the advice and prescription of an expert physician, three
>   medical tests A, B and C (say a urine test, a blood test, and an X-ray, to be specific). The physician has
>   imposed certain conditions on these tests:
>   (i) Tests B and C must be done only after test A is done.
>   (ii) Test A takes a full day; no other test can be carried out that day.
>   (iii) Each test can be completed on a single day; its implementation does not spill over to the next day.
>   (iv) Tests B and C can be carried out on the same day, or on separate days, in either order. When two
>   tests are done together on a single day, we consider them to be a single test. The order in which the
>   tests are performed is of no importance in this case.
>   (v) The tests must be completed within $n + 1$ days numbered $1, 2, 3,..., n + 1$.
>   The question now is: In how many different ways can tests A, B, C be performed?

My approach :
Let us consider $n=4$, so, number of days $=5$.
Case 1(B and C are being performed not on the same day):
So for this, clearly the ans is $\frac{^5P_5}{2!}-x$, where $x$ is the number of ways in which A is after B and C.
Case 2(B and C are on same day):
So, it's clerely $\frac{^5P_5}{3!}-y$, where $y$ is the number of ways in which A is after the single test (BC).
Am I correct? How to find $x$ and $y$? How to generalize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us just straightway jump into the general case, starting from the fact that we should ***first*** get test $A$ done.

For this we note that the test $A$ cannot be done on the $(n+1)^{\text{th}}$ day (why?). Let thus then safely assume that the test $A$ is done on the $k^{\text{th}}$ day.

Then, we can see that there are a total of $(n+1-k)$ possible days to take the tests $B$ and $C$. The total number of ways to do this are then $(n+1-k)^2$ (why?).

Thus, the total number of ways can be found by summing the value obtained before for $k=1$ to $n$ giving us: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(n+1-k)^2 = \,?$$

Comment: I understood that as B and C can not be taken on days $1,2,...k$, they are to be done one the remaining $(n+1-k)$ days...I did get nothing after that...please help me out

Comment: @amitayas Now, note that there is no restriction as to when tests B and C should be done. They can be done either on the same day or any of the possible $(n+1-k)$ days. So, ?

Comment: Oh! so  $(n+1-k)$ ways $\times$ $(n+1-k)$ ways...ok ok...I got it now...give me some time to follow the rest!

Comment: is ofc...wait 1 sec

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that B and C must be done 1 day before each other. Then, $x=2\cdot(3+2+1)=12$. Then find the value for 2 days after each other, which is $x=2\cdot(2+1)=6$. For 1, this would be $1\cdot2=2$. If you noticed, this is the sum of triangle numbers multiplied by $2$, or tetrahedral numbers. The formula, adapted would be: $$\frac{n(n-1)(n+1)}{3}$$ This is the value of $x$. $y$ is $4+3+2+1=10$, which is part of the triangle numbers or the sum of natural numbers. The formula would be: $$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$ Piercing the numbers together, the final answer is: $$n^2(n+1)-\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+\frac{n(n-1)(n+1)}{3}\right)$$

Comment: What is meant by " B and C must be done 1 day before each other"?